# Socket.io join another client to a room

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

My goal is when A user click on B user, they'll join in a room. I'm holding socket.id in array for all clients.

```
//CLIENT SIDE FOR A//
$('.chat-start').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var room_id = '72xaz132s'
        var target_id = $('.target').data('id');
        socket.emit('force join room', room_id, target_id);
    });

//SERVER SIDE FOR A AS AN EXAMPLE//

var clients {'customIDA' : socket.id for a, 'customIDB' : socket.id for b}

socket.on('force join room', function (roomid, customIDB) { 
        socket.join(chat_id); //CLIENT A JOINS ROOM//
    })
```

Client A joins room without problem, but how can i add also client B on same room ?

Comment: Have you tried a for loop yet?

Comment: I haven't. Actually, i don't know how to use '.join' function with spesific 'socket.id' which i can obtain inside array.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367765/joining-socket-io-room-on-connect

Comment: This topic shows how to join a room properly. But my problem is, i can't join B user with A user's action :/

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? i am facing same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `io.on("connection")` you can store socket object with user id as a object

```js
{"socket": socket, "id": user_id}
```

to array. Then find index from array:

```js
let user_index = users.findIndex(user => user.id == user_id);
```

And finally join to room.

```js
let socketB = users[user_index].socket;
socketB.join('room');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call join to subscribe the socket to a given channel:

```
// On connection join room
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('ROOM ID');
});
```

And then simply use to or in (they are the same) when broadcasting or emitting:

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event');
```

To leave a channel you call leave in the same fashion as join.

Documentation: https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

```js
function join() {
 // Run's once clicked
 console.log('Join function here');
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="join()">Join</a>
```

Comment: I have no problem for joining room on A side. The problem is, how can i join B user without any action after A user create and join that room ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe handle it server side? Have a dictionary that stores User Ids and the Socket Id, you can store this information `io.on("connection")`. Then when User A does the process of creating the room, send to the server side the room id and something that identifies User B. Server side figures out the socket id of User B and joins them to the room.

Comment: I have an array that holds users and their socket id. So when user A create a room, i already know B's socket id. How can i join user B to that room ? User a join that room via socket.join('room'). Is that work like socketIDForB.join('room') ?

Answer (score 0):

This method is a bit of a hack, but it does allow you to force any specified socket into a room entirely server-side, once you have their socket ID, without maintaining another object array. SocketIO (v2.x) stores room allocations in two places to make things fun.

```
// $targetSocket is the socket ID of the connection you want to force into a room
    
$roomArray = $io->sockets->connected[$targetSocket]->rooms; //socket's rooms stored here
$roomArray[$newRoom] = $newRoom; // add the new room to this array
$io->sockets->connected[$targetSocket]->rooms = $roomArray; // save the modified array
$io->sockets->adapter->add($targetSocket, $newRoom); // update the adapter too
```

This is obviously PHP but it will translate easily into js.

You can do the reverse to kick users out of rooms too:

```
unset($roomArray[$oldRoom]); //delete room key and value from this socket's array
// save the array here, see above
$io->sockets->adapter->del($targetSocket, $oldRoom); // delete from adapter
```

Use both at once for a leave and join system.

This may seem pointless when a socket can add or remove itself so easily with socket->join('ROOM'); but there *are* circumstances in which you may need to do this from outside the connection's socket, such a game function.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing a similar issue.

@Kouvolan Arnold's solution will work but having to store the socket object for each user is too much of a resource, especially when socket.io already stores them.

A simple solution here is for you to get the socket object already stored by locating it. The good news is that socket.io already provides that, see below.

```js
//v2.x or less
io.sockets.sockets[USER_SOCKET_ID_HERE]

//v3.x and 4.x
io.sockets.sockets.get(USER_SOCKET_ID_HERE)
```

The code below would have worked well in your case.

```js
//v2.x or less
io.sockets.sockets[clientSocketId].join(roomid);

//v3.x and 4.x
io.sockets.sockets.get(clientSocketId).join(roomid);
```

Thanks