# Socket IO server does not emit message to custom room

Tags: javascript, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm building a lobby system where players can invite each other using Socket io version 4. Currently, it works by the client sending a simple request to create a room and then join it. After that the client should be able to emit messages to the other clients in the room. The problem is that the server receives the message but never forwards it to any client in the room.

Currently, my code looks like this

**Server**

```js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    const token = extractToken(socket.handshake.headers)
    const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true })
    const user = decodedToken.payload.user_information

    socket.leave(socket.id)
    socket.id = user.id
    socket.join(socket.id)

    socket.on('room', (room) => {
        socket.join(room)
    })

    socket.on('lobby', async (data) => {
        const { message, room } = data
        console.log(data)
        socket.to(room).emit('lobby', message)
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(user.username + ' has disconnected')
    })
})
```

**Client**

```js
const connect = () => {
    socket = io('localhost:8080', {
        extraHeaders: {
            authorization: 'bearer ' + token
        }
    })

    socket.on('lobby', (msg) => {
        console.log(msg)
        const item = document.createElement('li')
        item.textContent = msg
        messagesList.appendChild(item)
    })
}

messageForm.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (messageInput.value) {
        await socket.emit('room', roomInput.value)
        socket.emit('lobby', { 'message': messageInput.value, 'room': roomInput.value })
        messageInput.value = ''
    }
})
```

I can emit global messages to all clients but cannot target a specific room. I know my clients join the room when they send the request but they don't get any messages from the room.
I also don't think that my clients disconnect halfway through because it doesn't show up on the disconnect logs I have.

I have tried to use the default namespace even though I don't use namespaces, to begin with, I have both tried to have the server and the socket emit the message, I have made sure that the message object is not undefined and I have made sure that the room name is a string but none of these things have worked so far.

The server receives a message but doesn't emit it to the clients inside the room it's supposed to send it to.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the join is succeeding? According to everything I can find, the socket used for `.join()` is (a fresh) one given by a connection (`socket.on('connection'...)`), _not_ the server socket as your server sample seems to be doing. For example, Bk Razor's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367765/joining-socket-io-room-on-connect) and the Socket#rooms section [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-socket-instance/).

Comment: @NickGris I updated the server example to provide more context. I looked through your links however I was unfortunately not able to get it working. 
I have this one function that logs whenever clients join a room and according to it, the clients do join the room upon request.
´io.of("/").adapter.on("join-room", (room, id) => {
    console.log('socket' + id + 'has joined room' + room)
})´

Comment: Wow, this twisted my head for a while. Your (revised) line `socket.to(room).emit('lobby', message)` should be `io.to(room).emit('lobby', message)`. See if that sorts it out. The rooms are a feature of `io`, the server, not `socket`, the connection to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it finally. The problem was that I replaced the automatically generated socket id with my own.
It works after I removed:

```
socket.id = user.id
```

I'll just have to save the client id somewhere else.