# node.js - what is a good implementation of sending different data to different clients?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, here's the thing. I'm writing a small web application using node.js with my partner. In this application, we need to send different data to different clients. Right now, I implemented this demand using scripts like below:

```
io.sockets.to(ClientId).emit();
```

Although the code works well, I'm still not sure if it's a proper way to implement the needs, which is, sending different data to different clients.

So, any advice? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SU! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You could use socket.io rooms.

```
socket1.join("room1");
socket2.join("room1");

socket3.join("room2");
socket4.join("room2");

io.to("room1").emit("event", "data");
io.to("room2").emit("event", "different data");
```

The code above would send `"data"` to `socket1` and `socket2` and send `"different data"` to `socket3` and `socket4`.

More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150220/creating-rooms-in-socket-io).