# Socket.io - Socket splitting into rooms

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to create a multiplayer game that creates new rooms for each *two* sockets that connect. How would I go about doing this? Can someone please provide an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Rooms in Socket.io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150220/creating-rooms-in-socket-io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point you can use the following example

```
const io = require('socket.io')()

/* room to join next connected socket */
let prevRoom = null

io.on('connection', socket => {
  let room

  if (prevRoom == null) {
    /* create new room if there is no room with one player */
    room = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)
    prevRoom = room
  } else {
    /* join existing room with one player and mark that it is now complete */
    room = prevRoom
    prevRoom = null
  }

  socket.join(room)

  /* send message from one socket in this room to another */
  socket.on('message', data => {
    socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('message', data)
  })
})

io.listen(3000)
```

The problem with this example is that in case one player from a room leaves the game, another will remain alone until he or she refreshes the page. Depending on the application you may need to add some logic here.