# how to send typing alert and message to users in a particular room using nodejs socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

The code below works fine by broadcasting **typing notification** and **chat messages** to all connected users.

**Here is what I want:** How do I send typing notification and chat messages only to users connected to a particular room
say Room1, Room2 etc.

here is the code

**index.html**

```
var socket = io(); 
var user = 'nancy';
function submitfunction(){
  var from = 'nancy';
  var message = 'hello Nancy';
  socket.emit('chatMessage', from, message);
}

function notifyTyping() {
  var user = 'nancy' 
  socket.emit('notifyUser', user);
}

socket.on('chatMessage', function(from, msg){
  //sent message goes here
});

socket.on('notifyUser', function(user){
    $('#notifyUser').text(nancy is typing ...');
  setTimeout(function(){ $('#notifyUser').text(''); }, 10000);
});
```

**server.js**

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection', function(socket){ 
  socket.on('chatMessage', function(from, msg){
    io.emit('chatMessage', from, msg);
  });


  socket.on('notifyUser', function(user){
    io.emit('notifyUser', user);
  });
});
```

am using npm installed socket.io **^2.3.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send the message to a specific room, you will have to create and join a room with roomId. Below is a basic code snippet

```
//client side
const socket = io.connect();
socket.emit('create', 'room1');

// server side code
  socket.on('create', function(room1) {
    socket.join(room1);
  });

To emit data to a specific room 

// sending to all clients in 'room1'except sender
  socket.to('room1').emit('event',data);

// sending to all clients in 'room1' room, including sender
 io.in('room1').emit('event', 'data');
```

You can follow this question for details on how to create a room?

[Creating Rooms in Socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150220/creating-rooms-in-socket-io)

This `emit` cheat sheet might also be useful:
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/emit.md

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. I will try it out